# Is there software like Mac's 'Logic Pro'?

Tags: music

I'm a hobbyist musician; for quite a while, I used a program for Mac's called 'Logic Pro', apparently this is the industry standard application for music creation. (Indeed, at my College if you don't have it at home you can't do any music courses)

So, is there anything like it for Ubuntu?

Please please PLEASE don't say "Audacity"; Logic Pro does so much more then edit audio (for example, I can quite easily create entire songs, minus the lyrics, by selecting instruments and their notes.) and Audacity is...well...laughable in comparison.

Comment: My son uses Logic Pro; I use Linux and various music applications. I can tell you up front that Linux has NOTHING that matches Logic Pro. I'm sorry to say that, but that's the truth of the matter. All of the applications mentioned by other respondents are good, but none offers the full range of Logic Pro functionality, nor are they as easy or intuitive to use. (Anyone who has tried setting up, for example, Rosegarden for the first time will either know what I mean or is a geek.) I'd be happy to help develop a requirements specification, but I'm not a programmer, so someone else would have to t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for a synthesiser. Ubuntu Studio (the version of Ubuntu that's for doing audio, video, animation, etc) has a list of synthesisers on https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio/PackageList  So maybe try installing [fluidsynth](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/fluidsynth) and [qsynth](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/qsynth) (the GUI for fluidsynth) and see how that is?

Answer (score 6):

Linux MultiMedia Studio

```
sudo apt-get install lmms
```

is an easy to use but powerful piece of software for creating music.

[image: lmms]

It is included in [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org/), which I highly recommend you to use as it bundles many other useful software for audio creation and editing. You can install Ubuntu Studio using the ISO image like you used to install ubuntu or you can install it from your existing intallation via the [ubuntustudio-desktop](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntustudio-desktop) package.

Ubuntu Studio comes bundled with lots of other software for media creation (video editing, graphics etc.) and also sets a new default theme. You may not want all of these things if you are primarily interested in audio software. For this reason, Ubuntu Studio is split up into a set of packages. For audio software you can install the [ubuntustudio-audio](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/ubuntustudio-audio) package.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few multitrack recording applications:

- [Ardour](http://www.ardour.org/)
- [Qtractor](http://qtractor.sourceforge.net/qtractor-index.html)
- [Rosegarden](http://www.rosegardenmusic.com/)

[linux-sound.org](http://linux-sound.org) has links to various audio production software, and you may also want to look into [Ubuntu Studio](http://www.ubuntustudio.org/).

Comment: Detail how the applications work.

Answer (score 1):

[Jokosher](http://www.jokosher.org/) is another very popular, user-friendly multi-track sound mixing/recording setup.

Answer (score 0):

MuseScore is what I use for music notation.
http://musescore.org/

The features are comparable to that of the notation program Sibelius.